Mouse scroll distance
I am using a Logitech Lift bluetooth mouse on an Ubuntu 24.04 OS running on Wayland. I cannot seem to find a way of altering the scrolling distance of my mouse. For instance when reading a newspaper on Chrome a touch of the mouse wheel will shoot too far down on the page so that the start of the paragraph is out of sight above the page shown and I have to use the side bar to adjust the page correctly.
Gnome settings has ways of adjusting the speed and direction of the scroll but not the distance.
So if anyone knows how to alter the scrolling distance I would be most grateful to know it. What would be really nice would be to map a function onto one of the mouse buttons using "Input Remapper" to actively change the scroll distance according to the website layout.

In Firefox, you can control this by adjusting mousewheel.* in about:config.  Maybe Chrome has something similar?  Or you can use Firefox, if you like.

@End Antisemitic Hate There is a possibility in Chrome to enable/disable "Smooth Scrolling", but this doesn't affect the distance scrolled. :-(

Not a Ubuntu resource but might be useful for further research Arch Linux Q&A

@graham I especially mentioned I am using Wayland but the Info you linked to is exclusively X11 :-(

I specifically said might be useful for further research It wasn't intended as an answer. Do you not expect to do some research yourself yourself or just wait on others to provide solutions?

@graham Why the aggressive attitude? I did plenty of research before admitting defeat and asking the members of this forum if any of them had experienced this issue. In my naivety I had assumed that was still the purpose of the forum. Your comment didn't help at all because it linked to a debate about another OS running X11 when I clearly wrote that my issue was with Ubuntu 24.04 and Wayland. Do you imagine a link to a debate about Windows on DOS might be useful to me for further research?

it is usual to explain what you have tried and any errors encountered to assist in finding a solution. We cannot know what you have tried without telling us  Sometimes an article from elsewhere sparks an opportunity to explore further. Simply that and in no way aggressive.
